# Multiplication in C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case, multiplication

I'm new to C# and tried the following program on multiplication using Switch. The program is perfectly going thru the Switch cases, but the multiplied result is not displaying in the console. Can you please help:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    int _pLicense = 50;
    int _sLicense = 100;
    int _eLicense = 150;
    String lType;
    int nSeats;
Console.WriteLine("\n1.Personal License\n2.Startup License\n3.Enterprise License");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the license type");
        lType = Console.ReadLine();
        //lType = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


switch(lType)
    {
        case "1":
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of seats");
            nSeats = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //Console.WriteLine(_pLicense);
            int Cost = _pLicense*nSeats;
            Console.WriteLine("Personal License Cost : $", +Cost);
            break;
        case "2":
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of seats");
            nSeats = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //Console.WriteLine(_sLicense);
            Cost = (_sLicense * nSeats);
            Console.WriteLine("Startup License Cost : $", Cost);
            break;
        case "3":
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of seats");
            nSeats = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //Console.WriteLine(_pLicense);
            Cost = (_eLicense * nSeats);
            Console.WriteLine("Enterprise License Cost : $", Cost);
            break;
        default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Type");
           break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you notice in your first case you have +Cost?

Comment: @ShellNinja Actually the issue is the comma before that.

Comment: Yes that's the issue, regardless - there was an unnecessary +, which is why I didn't answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing formaterlike {0}

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enterprise License Cost : ${0}", Cost);
```

Comment: Perfect, when I changed the format it worked well. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 6):

Change your `Console.Writeline` to

```
Console.WriteLine($"Personal License Cost : ${Cost}");
```

and

```
Console.WriteLine($"Enterprise License Cost : ${Cost}");
```

You can also format Cost using `{Cost:d}` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting.

It is also advisable that you don't use int.Parse because it will throw an error if a character is entered. So change the code to something like

```
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int nSeats)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Enterprise License Cost : ${Cost}");
}
else
{
    //Try again
}
```

You don't have to declare nSeats at the top, and it handles the error.

This is how I would've write the code

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int nSeats = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("\n1.Personal License\n2.Startup License\n3.Enterprise License");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the license type");
    var lType = Console.ReadLine();  //ReadLine returns a string, so it will automatically make lType a string
    int _LicenseCost = lType == "1" ? 50 : lType == "2" ? 100 : lType == "3" ? 150 : 0;
    if(_LicenseCost > 0)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of seats");
            if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nSeats))
                break;
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
        }
        Console.WriteLine((lType == "1" ? "Personal" : lType == "2" ? "Startup" : lType == "3" ? "Enterprise" : "") + $" License Cost : ${_LicenseCost * nSeats}");
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("License type is not valid. Good bye!");
}
```

Comment: It is very important to mention that this method is ONLY for C# 6.0. anything before won't support this. Pre C# 6.0 is [gulshan arora](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51966630/2748412) answer.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, simply use the following:

```
var cost = (_sLicense * nSeats);
Console.WriteLine("Startup License Cost : " + cost);
```

Comment: you probably did not use `var cost`

Comment: Using `var` would have nothing to do with this, more likely they still had the comma in there.

Comment: The op is using variable `Cost` in his code, so if he copy-pasted just the last line of the snippet `Console.WriteLine("Startup License Cost : " + cost);` it most likely did not get the correct output

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing code to displaying actual result. You can try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Personal licence : " + cost);
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, declare your Cost variable outside the switch statement. You can declare it along with your other variables.
Secondly, assign and display the Cost variable in each case of the switch statement.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    int _pLicense = 50;
    int _sLicense = 100;
    int _eLicense = 150;
    String lType;
    int nSeats;
    int Cost;

Console.WriteLine("\n1.Personal License\n2.Startup License\n3.Enterprise License");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the license type");
        lType = Console.ReadLine();
        //lType = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


switch(lType)
    {
        case "1":
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of seats");
            nSeats = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //Console.WriteLine(_pLicense);
            Cost = _pLicense*nSeats;
            Console.WriteLine("Personal License Cost : $" + Cost);
            break;
        case "2":
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of seats");
            nSeats = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //Console.WriteLine(_sLicense);
            Cost = (_sLicense * nSeats);
            Console.WriteLine("Startup License Cost : $" + Cost);
            break;
        case "3":
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of seats");
            nSeats = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //Console.WriteLine(_pLicense);
            Cost = (_eLicense * nSeats);
            Console.WriteLine("Enterprise License Cost : $" + Cost);
            break;
        default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Type");
           break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String formatting example:

```
string name = "Fred";
String.Format("Name = {0}, hours = {1:hh}", name, DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: It's better to add some explanation about your answer